# Cannot connect to Kafka running on a virtual machine

Tags: c#, ubuntu, apache-kafka, vmware-player

I installed kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1 on a Ubuntu 12.04 (Linux ubuntu 3.8.0-44-generic) hosted by vmware player 6.0.3 build-1895310. On the host machine (Windows 8) I am using the C# client from https://github.com/Jroland/kafka-net. The ip of the kafka machine is correctly configured in C# code, the topic "test" is accordingly created in kafka etc. I get the following messages:

> No connection to:http://:9092/.  Attempting to re-connect...
>   Type a message and press enter...
>   Awaiting message from: http://:9092/
>   BrokerRouter: Refreshing metadata for topics: test
>   Failed re-connection to:http://:9092/.  Will retry in:1000
>   Failed re-connection to:http://:9092/.  Will retry in:2000
>   Failed re-connection to:http://:9092/.  Will retry in:4000

The same client connects to a physical linux machine with kafka.

I would like to be able to develop with kafka running as a virtual machine. How could I solve the communication issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I never used the c# version, but is your producer configure correctly?

From the error message, it seems that it doesn't have the IP/DNS configured...

> No connection to:http://:9092/

Comment: Thanks for reply. The machine holding kafka is specified through its IPv4 address, when running the client.